# Vagrant creates numerous trash config files and directories

Tags: vagrant

I'm using Vagrant with Docker as a provider.

Whenever I launch `vagrant` with any command, the directory gets populated with four files, prefixed with 'vagrant', e.g. 'vagrant20150902-10813-1p2j0fh', and a directory, prefixed with 'd', e.g. 'd20150902-10813-14u60qc'.

Neither of those gets automatically deleted, so after few restarts my pwd gets cluttered with groups of files and directories, identical in contents:

[image: cluttered dir]

[image: cluttered dir 2]

Has anyone had such trouble? Perhaps there's a problem with synced folders?

## Contents of files

**vagrant%date%-%id%-%rand1%** (e.g. 'vagrant20150902-12033-1j2np7i') and **vagrant%date%-%id%-%rand2%** (e.g. 'vagrant20150902-12033-v7vbh4') are empty.

**vagrant%date%-%id%-%rand2%2** (e.g. 'vagrant20150902-12033-v7vbh42') looks like a Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
source "http://gems.hashicorp.com"
gem "vagrant", "= 1.7.2"
group :plugins do
gem "vagrant-share", nil, {}
end
```

**vagrant%date%-%id%-%rand2%2.lock** (e.g. 'vagrant20150902-12033-v7vbh42.lock') looks like a Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  remote: http://gems.hashicorp.com/
  specs:
    akami (1.2.2)
      gyoku (>= 0.4.0)
      nokogiri
    builder (3.2.2)
    celluloid (0.16.0)
      timers (~> 4.0.0)
    childprocess (0.5.5)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    ffi (1.9.6)
    gssapi (1.0.3)
      ffi (>= 1.0.1)
   ...

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  vagrant (= 1.7.2)
  vagrant-share
```

directories *d%date%-%id%-%rand3%* (e.g. 'd20150902-12033-1gkuid5') contain single identical file *config*:

```
BUNDLE_PATH: "/home/username/.vagrant.d/gems"
```

**EDIT**: Neither project Gemfile, nor Gemfile.lock contain gem 'vagrant', I have installed it from .deb package. Vagrant version is 1.7.4

### UPDATE

This is totally looking weird. I traced the trouble to [vagrant bin](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/v1.7.4/bin/vagrant#L111) that calls `Vagrant::Bundle#deinit`:

```
at_exit(&Vagrant::Bundler.instance.method(:deinit))
```

[Here's](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/v1.7.4/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb#L81) how the method looks in the source code:

```
def deinit
   File.unlink(ENV["BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG"]) rescue nil
   File.unlink(ENV["BUNDLE_CONFIG"]) rescue nil
   File.unlink(ENV["GEMFILE"]) rescue nil
end
```

It tries unlinking `ENV["BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG"]`, which is a directory, causing an error that is subsequently silenced. Besides, `ENV["GEMFILE"]` was not defined (`ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"]` was), so this line would cause suppressed error, too.

For now I had to override `Vagrant::Bundle#deinit` in vagrant bin:

```
Vagrant::Bundler.class_eval do
  def deinit
    file1 = ENV["BUNDLE_CONFIG"][0..-2]
    file2 = ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"][0..-2]
    gemfile_lock = "#{ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"]}.lock"
    FileUtils.rm_rf(ENV["BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG"])
    File.unlink(ENV["BUNDLE_CONFIG"], ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"], file1, file2, gemfile_lock)
  end
end

# Schedule the cleanup of things
at_exit(&Vagrant::Bundler.instance.method(:deinit))
```

There must be a cleaner way to do this, too bad I haven't found it yet.

**Upd2**: [Here's](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/pull/4870) the issue that caused these changes, and [here's](https://github.com/michaeljb/vagrant/commit/8a673eaab780b242d6becb3e4a681956695a7404) the commit. Perhaps I am missing some flag or env variable?

**Upd3**: Filed an issue at [github](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6231)